# Add custom content to nonexistent page

Tags: 404-error, actions, rewrite-rules, template-redirect, post-content

I am trying to add content to what would otherwise be a 404 page.
For example I want to define post content for mysite.com/existing-page/imaginary-page instead of showing the 404 page.  I've tried several different approaches and none work, so I greatly appreciate your help. 
My actual structure is this: mysite.com/personal-development/class.  mysite.com/personal-development exists but mysite.com/personal-development/class does not.  mysite.com/personal-development/class will display altered content from mysite.com/personal-development

if seems like add_rewrite_rule would work if the class page actually existed.

```
add_action( 'init', 'dynamic_classes_class_type_rewrite' );
function dynamic_classes_class_type_rewrite()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_rewrite_tag( '%personal-development%', '([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^personal-development/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?page_id=17318&class_type=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );    
}
```

This one catches the page and cancels the 404.  It then shows the home page content but does not use the template style-sheets or allow me to change the content.  The example below is my attempt to get the appropriate content and display it.  I also tried displaying a different template.  I was able to display the template, but was still not able to display any content.

```
add_filter('template_redirect', 'dynamic_classes_class_type_redirect' );
function dynamic_classes_class_type_redirect() 
{
//for best seo I am setting up a redirect for pages.
    global $wp, $wpdb, $wp_query;
    if(!$post_title=get_post($post)->post_title)//looks like we hit a 404
    {
        $url=explode('/',dynamic_classes_page_url());//see if its one of our dynamically created pages.
        if(count($url)>4)//we need to make sure this long enough
        {
            $db_prefix= $wpdb->prefix;
            $sql='SELECT ID
                  FROM '.$db_prefix.'posts
                  WHERE post_name=\''.implode('',array_slice($url,-2,1)).'\' /*get the second to last*/
                  LIMIT 1';
            $rs_class = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
            if($rs_class)
            {
                status_header( 200 );
                $wp_query->is_404=false;
                wp_reset_query();
                setup_postdata(get_post($rs_class[0]->ID));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

add_action and 'the_post' will allow me to alter content as I need to, but not for 404s - even if I cancelled the 404 as in the above example.

```
add_action( 'the_post', 'my_the_post_action' );
function my_the_post_action( $post_object ) {
    $post_object->post_content='Programmer test.';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, you add the rewrite tag `personal-development`, but then you use the rewrite tag `class_type` inside your rewrite rule. That method would work if you fixed that error, and assuming `17318` is the page id of your `personal-development` page. You could then use `get_query_var('personal_development')` in the template or a template hook, to check what's been requested.

```
add_action( 'init', 'dynamic_classes_class_type_rewrite' );
function dynamic_classes_class_type_rewrite()
{
    add_rewrite_tag( '%personal_development%', '([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^personal-development/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?page_id=17318&personal_development=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );    
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but only got a 404. Can you elaborate on the template hook?  My goals is to either have the url mysite.com/personal-development/class process equivalently to mysite.com/personal-development/?class_type=class where I can change the post content before it displays, or be able to alter the 404 post content before it displays.  17318 is the personal-development page id.  Thank you